# Martin's Maximum implies stationary/club Chang's conjecture?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, forcing, infinite-combinatorics

Chang's Conjecture (CC) states: for any $f: [\omega_2]^{<\omega} \to \omega_1$, there exists a set $X\subset \omega_2$ of order type $\omega_1$ such that $|f''[X]^{<\omega}|\leq \aleph_0$.
Martin's Maximum (MM) implies (a strengthening of) it.

My question: does MM imply the following strengthenings:

1. stat-CC: for any $f: [\omega_2]^{<\omega} \to \omega_1$, there exists a set $X\subset \omega_2$ of order type $\omega_1$ **and $X$ is stationary in $\sup X$** such that $|f''[X]^{<\omega}|\leq \aleph_0$.
2. club-CC: for any $f: [\omega_2]^{<\omega} \to \omega_1$, there exists a set $X\subset \omega_2$ of order type $\omega_1$ **and $X$ is closed in $\sup X$** such that $|f''[X]^{<\omega}|\leq \aleph_0$.

Comment: Do you know any model where (2) holds?

Comment: no idea. it contradicts a version of simultaneous stationary reflection: there exists a partition $\langle S_i\subset S^2_0: i<\omega_1\rangle$ such that on club many $\gamma \in S^2_1$, all of them reflect simultaneously. it is weaker in the sense we don't want any such sequence to reflect but just one.

Comment: Relevant: https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.09280

Comment: the proof seems glitchy. or do you know of a fix?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read it yet.

Comment: The comment on the Arxiv paper referenced above says:
"Theorem 12, and the proof of Claim 13, are not correct (thanks to Omer Ben-Neria for pointing this out). The notion in Definition 7 is inconsistent with ZFC"

The pdf is no longer available on the site.